# How to Set Log directory to desired location in UI Path

Tags: logging, uipath

By default, UI Path stores all the logs into %LocalAppData%/UiPath/Logs folder. I would like the logs to be stored in my desired location.
Anybody know how to change this default setting? Please help me with your inputs.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Default log settings can be overridden by editing the NLog.config file in UIPath installer folder.

But this will update the default settings for all the BOTs that are running in the environments and not to a specific BOT alone.

Answer (score 0):

In UiPath Studio 2020.10.4, you can modify this setting from file named: UiPath.Studio.Analyzer.exe.config, and the location of this file is:

```
C:\Users\{User Name}\AppData\Local\UiPath\app-20.10.4
```

You need to  modify the following variable to desired file path:

variable name="StudioLoggingDirectory" value="${specialfolder:folder=LocalApplicationData}/UiPath/Logs"